# SQLite: How do I substitute the identifier in a column with its equivalent string from another table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using Pokemon as an experimental data set for my honours thesis. Using SQLite I would like to construct decks from a set of cards.

What I have going on for now is two tables, decks and cards.

[Fig 1. Cards Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRYWH.png)

And decks

[Fig 2. Decks Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17a0X.png)

I want to substitute the integer identifiers in the card_# columns from decks with their strings from the cardname column in cards.

Such that, I would get

```
{ a, pickachu, 20, charmander 30, water, 10 }
{ b, ...                                    }
                    .
                    .
                    .
{ j, ...                                    }
```

So far I've been using a myriad of joins, union, clause, and operators to try and figure this out, but I am very much a beginner and none of my attempts have worked so far.

Or is my data organization the problem?

Thanks for any help in advance!

EDIT: I realize I could update it, is this logical choice?

Comment: I suggest you read about *data normalization*.  With good design you will have reasonable queries.

Comment: I'll definitely give that a go! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    --A self join ended up being the solution!

select decks.deckname, a.cardname as card1, decks.wt_1, b.cardname as card2, decks.wt_2, c.cardname as card3, decks.wt_3 

from decks

    join cards a
    on decks.card_1=a.uniquecard
    join cards b
    on decks.card_2=b.uniquecard
    join cards c
    on decks.card_3=c.uniquecard;
```

[Complete Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc1sq.png)